# What Swift Version Should I be using?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, version, backwards-compatibility

I have a few questions related to Swift Versions.

I am currently writing an app in Swift 2.2 I am planning on releasing the app to the App Store before iOS 10 is released. Does that mean I need to stay using Swift 2.2 until iOS 10 is released?

Once iOS 10 is released, if I upgrade to Swift 3.0, will I still be able to build for iOS 8 and 9?

What is the purpose of Swift 2.3? Overall, I'm trying to understand what the optimal time to be upgrading versions of Swift is while maintaining compatibility with older iOS versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be able to build for iOS 7, 8 and 9 with Swift 3.0. Swift 2.3 is only to give more time for developers to transition to swift 3.0, considering swift 3.0 is not retro-compatible. If you can move to swift 3.0 right now because you are starting a new project and do not plan to release until september, I would suggest to do it. If not, I would suggest to stay at version 2.2 to ensure you can publish to the app store.
Swift 2.3 won't be eternally supported by Xcode (nor Swift 3.0 if it loses compatibility), so as soon as Golden master gets released, I would suggest to get on 3.0.

Comment: Great, thanks. Just to confirm, I can submit a project with Swift 3.0 right now to the App Store, before iOS 10 comes out?

Comment: Apps built with beta versions of XCode are not accepted to the app store.You will have to wait for the golden master https://developer.apple.com/support/beta-software/

Comment: Ok, I'll accept the answer, but just put the warning out there that this answer recommends someone in my position to start using Swift 3.0 now, however I explained in the question that I will be releasing before iOS 10 (and therefore before Swift 3.0 is out), so someone in this position should not start with Swift 3.0 or they will be stuck until the GM is out to release.

Comment: what if i would like to keep using Xcode 7.3 and Swift 2.2? i've seen that apps work perfectly on ios 10 too, no need to switch to Swift 3 and Xcode 8 (it has bugs on Storyboard without Autolayout and date comparison).

Answer (score 2):

I'll offer counter-advice. Don't count your beta software until it's hatched. If you have a near deadline, don't make your product depend on a beta version of Xcode. (Swift 3 requires Xcode 8.) Beta software doesn't ship until it ships.

Swift 3 represents a number of non-backwards-compatible changes from Swift 2. All the changes appear to be for the better, and worth investing the time to learn, but it makes development decisions difficult during this transition phase.

We will be able to build apps written in Swift 3 for iOS 7-10, but we won't be able to ship those apps until Apple agrees to accept apps built with Xcode 8. Apple MAY allow apps built with Xcode 8 to be submitted to the App store before the Xcode 8 GM release, but they may not.